# How to define the nl_sock in the libnl?

Tags: c

I download libnl3 source code, but did not found out where define the struct nl_sock.Can any one help?

Comment: Please be more specific about your question. What OS are you using? Have you included all header-files?

Comment: I am using ubuntu12. I wanna use python call libnl3 library.I`m newbie here,Sorry.

Comment: no need to be sorry. Just if you want people to help, you need to be specific as possible. Have you googled your problem? See [here](http://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/doc/api/group__socket.html#details) and as Randy Howard said, have you included the headers?

Comment: The struct define in 'netlink-private/types.h'.Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the netlink include files that came with the library.  Start in netlink/socket.h, netlink/netlink.h, etc.

Comment: I use 'grep' command that list all ‘nl_sock’. This struct just define like as 'struct nl_sock;'. And I look in the netlink include files, but not find it.

Comment: It sounds like you might not have the library and associated headers installed correctly.  Also, you may not be including the correct header files in your own code.  Have you checked here http://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/doc/api/index.html

Comment: Include 'netlink-private/types.h', prolem is solved.Thanks.